# Deleting in database?

Tags: android, database, sql-insert, corresponding-records, delete-record

I have a question about the databases in Android. I had created in my app a database. If I delete a record from database, for example the last one, and after that I insert a new record in database, the new record is not saved in database in the row where I deleted the other record. That row is empty. It is saved in the next row. Why? Should I do something?

Comment: What are your columns for this table? Do you have an _id column?

Comment: Yes,I have an _id column

Comment: See slunds answer, that column is being autoincremented so you can't assign it a value, it will just get the next sequential number for the value with each insert.

Comment: Yes,I understand. In my app I used AUTOINCREMENT. If I delete autoincrement, my table is not changed. I have to create a new project to change the tables from database?

Comment: A column named _id will autoincrement even without that constraint given.

Comment: That means that I don't have to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about an sqlite DB?

If your rowid is a field declared using AUTOINCREMENT, then (from the docs) the "ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has **ever before existed** in that same table".

You can read about the autoincrement algorithm here: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Note that you do NOT have to use AUTOINCREMENT to have your primary key auto select a rowid.